# can I add a list of variable names to a combobox in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

I have a long list of arrays, and I want to make a dropdown box to see all the names of the arrays. I don't want to pre-enter the names to the dropdown box, and I want to avoid the multiple lines of dynamically entering the names.

eg,

`int[] Brett = { 24, 64, 83 };`

`int[] Tony = { 32, 78, 27 };`

The combobox dropdowns would show Brett and Tony

I am new to programming so if there is a basic solution I would understand I would prefer it to an advanced way of doing it. Thanks for any help at all though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you have [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), but [`nameof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) is the answer to  your local question:

```
ComboBox mybox = new ComboBox();
mybox.Items.Add(nameof(Brett));
mybox.Items.Add(nameof(Tony));
```

Let's try to sort out your case. I think that use long list of variables is not good idea so the better way is to use list of classes or Dictionary like this:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
parameters.Add("Brett", new [] { 24, 64, 83 });
parameters.Add("Tony", new [] { 32, 78, 27 });
```

It'll help you to add items easier:

```
foreach(var kvp in parameters)
    mybox.Items.Add(kvp.Key);
```

The alternative with classes is in the code below:

```
public class PersonParams
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int[] Params { get; }
    public PersonParams(string name, params int [] p)
    {
        Name = name;
        Params = p;
    }
}
...
var persons = new List<PersonParams>();
persons.Add(new PersonParams("Brett", 24, 64, 83));
persons.Add(new PersonParams("Tony", 32, 78, 27));
...
foreach(var p in persons)
    mybox.Items.Add(p.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. using ```nameof``` looks like I would have to list every variable though, which is what I'm trying to avoid because i have a very long list of variables. (I edited the post to mention it)

Comment: @user3733200 ok that's good. This is the reason i mentioned the XY-problem. So I'm updating the question.